# Risk coefficient of logistics distribution

Tags: probability, limits, statistics, functions, probability-distributions

I'm doing this exercise about risk coefficent,and i do this but i think is incorrect and i don't know where.

I have
$f(x)= \frac{e^{\frac{x-\alpha }{\beta }}}{\beta\left ( 1-e^{\frac{x-\alpha }{\beta }} \right )}$ and $F(x)=\frac{1}{1-e^{\frac{x-\alpha }{\beta }}}$ with $-\infty < x < \infty$
And I have to calculate this coefficent $$h_{X}(t)=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac{\mathbb{P}\left ( t\leq X< t+\epsilon |X\geq t \right )}{\epsilon }$$
$$=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\left ( \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right )\left ( \frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{t+\epsilon -\alpha }{\beta }}}- \frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{t-\alpha}{\beta }}}\right ) $$
$$=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\left ( \frac{e^{\frac{t-\alpha }{\beta }}-e^{\frac{t+\epsilon -\alpha }{\beta }}}{1+e^{\frac{t-\alpha }{\beta }}+e^{\frac{t+\epsilon -\alpha }{\beta }}+e^{\frac{2t+\epsilon -2\alpha }{\beta }}} \right )\left ( \frac{1}{\varepsilon } \right ) $$
$$ =\left ( \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{\frac{t-\alpha }{\beta }}-e^{\frac{t+\epsilon -\alpha }{\beta }}}{1+e^{\frac{t-\alpha }{\beta }}+e^{\frac{t+\epsilon -\alpha }{\beta }}+e^{\frac{2t+\epsilon -2\alpha }{\beta }}} \right )\left ( \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon } \right )$$

Comment: What is $F(x)$? It cannot be a CDF on the domain $-\infty<x<\infty$, since it would take on negative values.

Comment: As said please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution
And do the question require you to derive from the first principle, or you can directly use the result like $h_X(t) = f_X(t) / [1 - F_X(t)]$, where $f_X, F_X$ is the pdf and CDF of $X$ respectively.

Comment: To repeat the point, if this really is a logistic distribution then I would have expected you to have 
$f(x)= \frac{e^{\frac{x-\alpha }{\beta }}}{\beta\left ( 1+e^{\frac{x-\alpha }{\beta }} \right )^2}= \frac{e^{-\frac{x-\alpha }{\beta }}}{\beta\left ( 1+e^{-\frac{x-\alpha }{\beta }} \right )^2}$ and 
$F(x)= \frac{e^{\frac{x-\alpha }{\beta }}}{ 1+e^{\frac{x-\alpha }{\beta }} }= \frac{1}{ 1+e^{-\frac{x-\alpha }{\beta }}}$ so you might want to check your signs and exponents.